# how to fix the router posts in express

Tags: express, router

it is an API that should post and update posts .. i can't figure out what is missing in the code

postman keep telling me that they cannot post and return error :

Posts.Js:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) =>{
  try{
    const posts = await Post.find();
        res.json (posts);
  } catch (err) {
        res.json ({ message: err });
  }
});


//submit a posts

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
   const post = new Post({
       title: req.body.title,
       description: req.body.description
 });
    try {
       const savedPost = await post.save();
         res.json(savedPost);
    } catch (err) {
         res.json ({ message: err});
 }

 });
```

router post with no error

App js :

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require ('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require ('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

require('dotenv/config');



 app.use(cors());
 app.use(bodyParser.json());


 const postsRoute= require ( './routes/posts');

 app.use('/posts', postsRoute);
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting? Can you post the error here?

Comment: @Himakar : return from postman
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>Cannot POST /post/</pre>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: in `app.js` you said `'/posts'` but in the URL you got `Cannot POST /post/` are you sure you are calling `/posts/` extension??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you haven't included the router in `app.js` file.

Check if the router is exported properly and included in `app.js`

**app.js**

```
let postRouter = require('./path_to_router_dir/routerName');

app.use('/post', postRouter);
```

Check if you had done this. Please feel free to comment below for any clarifications or change in answer context.

Also remove '/' from end of post. The api end point must be `/post` and not `/post/`

Comment: You have used '/posts' but you have called '/post' from your client. Could just check that?

Comment: Could you post your app.js file in question

Comment: Change the app.use('/posts', postsRoute) to app.use('/post', postsRoute) and try.

Comment: Paste your app.js file in question. I would be helpful

Comment: Paste it in question, not in comments. It will be clear there with code formatting. Edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have exported router ?

I think you should use `let` instead.